# Storing objects to a list and searching for them

Tags: c#, list, search, textbox

I want to be able to create a series of objects in a list and then search for a particular result in that list (there may be 0, 1 or many hits) and then display the results in a text box.

This is what I have so far, but I can only seem to display the very last object I entered.

```
public partial class OrganiserWindow : Form
{
    public OrganiserWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    List<Album> AlbumList = new List<Album>();

    private void createAlbum_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AlbumList.Add(new Album(albumBox.Text, artistBox.Text));
    }

    private void searchAlbum_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var albumResult = from album in AlbumList
                          where album.AlbumName != null// == albumBox.Text
                          select new { Name = album.AlbumName, Artist = album.ArtistName };

        foreach (var item in albumResult)
        {
            albumResultBox.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, item.Name + " " + item.Artist);
        }
    }
}

public class Album
{
    private string albumName;
    private string artistName;

    public Album(string album, string artist)
    {
        albumName = album;
        artistName = artist;
    }

    public string AlbumName
    {
        get 
        { 
            return albumName; 
        }
        set 
        { 
            albumName = value; 
        }
    }

    public string ArtistName
    {
        get 
        { 
            return artistName; 
        }
        set 
        { 
            artistName = value; 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to use `+=` instead of `=`

```
albumResultBox.Text += String.Join(Environment.NewLine, item.Name + " " + item.Artist);
```

Comment: ... 1 character. Thank you very very much!

Comment: It's a simple answer. I wouldn't go so far as perfect, see below for details. Since you liked it, why not mark it as accepted? (click the tick)

Answer (score 0):

In each iteration you overwrite the text in textbox.  You should append to it.
Also TextBox.Text is never null.

This line will never add album wih AlbumName == null

```
AlbumList.Add(new Album(albumBox.Text, artistBox.Text));
```

So you always return all albums when you run this query

```
var albumResult = from album in AlbumList
                  where album.AlbumName != null
                  select new { Name = album.AlbumName, Artist = album.ArtistName };
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Yes it does provide an answer. Same as accepted one. Also it was written on the phone while on train so it's a bit harder to format the text. Now edited it.

Comment: ya..okie.. I came across this post when reviewing `low quality posts`. At that time it contained only 1 sentence. So I reviewed this as low quality.

Answer (score 0):

You are accumulating state. Strings are immutable and each call to += will create a new string object for each iteration. In your case it probably won't matter but as a matter of form you should do it like this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
...
sb.AppendFormat("{0} {1}\r\n", item.AlbumName, item.ArtistName);
```

then extract a finished string from `sb.ToString()`

You could greatly improve the legibiity of your code by overriding ToString()

```
public class Album
{
    public Album(string album, string artist)
    {
        albumName = album;
        artistName = artist;
    }

    public string AlbumName { get; set; }
    public string ArtistName { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() 
    {
        return string.Format("{0} {1}", AlbumName, ArtistName);
    }
}
```

allowing you to write

```
sb.AppendLine(item);
```

AppendLine implicitly calls ToString then appends CRLF.